# Cluster data in heat map in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Please see my plot below: 
[image]

my code:

```
 > head(data)
              X0      X1      X2       X3       X4       X5       X6        X7        X8        X9
 NM_001001144 6.52334 9.75243 5.62914 6.833650 6.789850 7.421440 8.675330 12.117600 11.551500  7.676900
 NM_001001327 1.89826 3.74708 1.48213 0.590923 2.915120 4.052600 0.758997  3.653680  1.931400  2.487570
 NM_001002267 1.70346 2.72858 2.10879 1.898050 3.063480 4.435810 7.499640  5.038870 11.128700 22.016500
 NM_001003717 6.02279 7.46547 7.39593 7.344080 4.568470 3.347250 2.230450  3.598560  2.470390  4.184450
 NM_001003920 1.06842 1.11961 1.38981 1.054000 0.833823 0.866511 0.795384  0.980946  0.731532  0.949049
 NM_001003953 7.50832 7.13316 4.10741 5.327390 2.311230 1.023050 2.573220  1.883740  3.215150  2.483410

pd <- as.data.frame(scale(t(data)))
pd$Time <- sub("_.*", "", rownames(pd))
pd.m <- melt(pd)
pd.m$variable <- as.numeric(factor(pd.m$variable, levels =     rev(as.character(unique(pd.m$variable))), ordered=F))
p <- ggplot(pd.m, aes(Time, variable))
p  + geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + scale_fill_gradient2(low=muted("blue"), high=muted("red")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("0h", "0.25h", "0.5h","1h","2h","3h","6h","12h","24h","48h")) + 
   theme_bw(base_size=20) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5, hjust=0, size=12),
   axis.text.y=element_text(size=12), strip.text.y=element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5, hjust=0.5, size=12),
   strip.text.x=element_text(size=12)) + labs(y="Genes", x="Time (h)", fill="")
```

Is there a way to cluster the plot so that the plot displays the dynamics in the time course. I would like to use the clustering that comes out of:

```
 hc.cols <- hclust(dist(t(data)))
```

[image]

Comment: Just fyi, I think it's frowned upon on SO to add "solved" to the title of your question.  I removed it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining the order of Timepoints in a dendrogram after you have applied `hclust` to your data:

```
data <- scale(t(data))
ord <- hclust( dist(data, method = "euclidean"), method = "ward.D" )$order
ord
[1]  2  3  1  4  8  5  6 10  7  9
```

The only thing you have to do then is transforming your Time-column to a `factor` where the factor levels are ordered by `ord`:

```
pd <- as.data.frame( data )
pd$Time <- sub("_.*", "", rownames(pd))
pd.m <- melt( pd, id.vars = "Time", variable.name = "Gene" )

pd.m$Gene <- factor( pd.m$Gene, levels = colnames(data), labels = seq_along( colnames(data) ) )
pd.m$Time <- factor( pd.m$Time, levels = rownames(data)[ord],  labels = c("0h", "0.25h", "0.5h","1h","2h","3h","6h","12h","24h","48h") )
```

The rest is done by `ggplot` automatically:

```
ggplot( pd.m, aes(Time, Gene) ) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low=muted("blue"), high=muted("red"))
```

[image]

Comment: awesome, exactly what I wonted. Looked great on the whole dataset.

Comment: Sorry, in the first version the data where clustered by genes. This is fixed now. But notice, that the time axis is now out of order of course. So maybe you want to cluster by gene instead of clustering by time. Unless you are not expecting recurring effects over time, this would also make more sense to me.

Comment: I actually want the version where it is clustered on time.

Comment: Sorry for bothering again. How would you go about to add row names in the plot?

Comment: Since you are assigning numbers to the gene names they appear like 1,2,3 and so on.

Comment: @user3741035 Oh, just leave this step `pd.m$Gene <- factor( pd.m$Gene, levels = colnames(data), labels = seq_along( colnames(data) ) )` out.

Comment: Hmm. If I leave it out it does not cluster.

Comment: Maybe because "genes" is not numberic?

Comment: @user3741035 are you clustering now by timepoints or genes? Leave the line, I told you to remove, but remove there the label assignment: `pd.m$Gene <- factor( pd.m$Gene, levels = colnames(data)[ord])`.

Comment: Is there a way to cluster based on time, but at the same time keep the order of the time points? Do I need to split the dataset then?

Comment: How? Clustering == changing order by similarity. But feel free to make a proper example and ask this as a separate question.

Comment: I have asked a separate question. Maybe my data is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `ggplot` supports this out of the box, but you can use `heatmap`:

```
 heatmap(
   as.matrix(dat), Rowv=NA,
   Colv=as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(as.matrix(dat)))))
 )
```

[image]

Note this won't look like yours because I'm just using the `head` of your data, not the whole thing.

Here we specify the clustering manually with a dendogram derived from your `hclust` with the `Colv` argument.  You can specify the clustering manually too through the `Colv` argument if the one used by default doesn't line up with what you want.

Comment: How do I set Rowv like the dendrogram above.

Comment: Try: `heatmap(as.matrix(dat), Rowv=NA, Colv=as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(as.matrix(dat))))))`

Comment: @user3741035, also, note I meant `Colv`, not `Rowv`

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd add you don't need to transform the columns in the `data.frame` to factors, you can use `ggplot`'s `scale_*_discrete` function to set the plotting order of axes.  Simply set the plotting order using the `limits` argument and the labels using the `labels` argument as shown below.

```
data<-read.table(text="X0      X1      X2       X3       X4       X5       X6        X7        X8        X9
 NM_001001144 6.52334 9.75243 5.62914 6.833650 6.789850 7.421440 8.675330 12.117600 11.551500  7.676900
 NM_001001327 1.89826 3.74708 1.48213 0.590923 2.915120 4.052600 0.758997  3.653680  1.931400  2.487570
 NM_001002267 1.70346 2.72858 2.10879 1.898050 3.063480 4.435810 7.499640  5.038870 11.128700 22.016500
 NM_001003717 6.02279 7.46547 7.39593 7.344080 4.568470 3.347250 2.230450  3.598560  2.470390  4.184450
 NM_001003920 1.06842 1.11961 1.38981 1.054000 0.833823 0.866511 0.795384  0.980946  0.731532  0.949049
 NM_001003953 7.50832 7.13316 4.10741 5.327390 2.311230 1.023050 2.573220  1.883740  3.215150  2.483410", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data <- scale(t(data))
ord <- hclust( dist(data, method = "euclidean"), method = "ward.D" )$order
pd <- as.data.frame( data )
pd$Time <- sub("_.*", "", rownames(pd))
pd.m <- melt( pd, id.vars = "Time", variable.name = "Gene" )
ggplot( pd.m, aes(Time, Gene) ) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=pd.m$Time[ord], labels = c("0h", "0.25h", "0.5h","1h","2h","3h","6h","12h","24h","48h"))+
  scale_y_discrete(limits=colnames(data), labels = seq_along(colnames(data)))+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low=muted("blue"), high=muted("red"))
```

[image]