# Ordering a factor to make a clustered ggplot heatmap but getting an odd error

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, cluster-analysis, heatmap

I'm trying to make a clustered heatmap, as described here [Cluster data in heat map in R ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528059/cluster-data-in-heat-map-in-r-ggplot) and am running into a perplexing bug.

I can make an un-clustered distance heatmap as follows:

```
library(vegan)
library(tidyverse)
data(varespec)
library(reshape2)
library(viridis)

# Calculate a distance matrix
vare.dist <- vegdist(varespec)

# Cluster the distance matrix.
vare.hc <- hclust(as.dist(vare.dist))

# Process and melt the distance matrix
vare.dist.long <- vare.dist %>% as.matrix %>% melt %>%
mutate(Var1 = as.character(Var1), Var2 = as.character(Var2))

# Plot the heatmap
vare.dist.long %>% #as.matrix %>% .[vare.hc$order, vare.hc$order] %>% melt %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + scale_fill_viridis(direction = 1) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270, hjust = 0, vjust = 0.5
                                ))
```

[image: unclustered heatmap]

To cluster the heatmap, I need to convert `vare.dist.long$Var1` and `vare.dist.long$Var2` into properly ordered factors. I would think that I could do that as

```
# Step 1: works without complaint
vare.dist.long1 <- vare.dist.long %>% mutate(Var1 = factor(Var1, levels = Var1[vare.hc$order]))
# Step 2: throws error
vare.dist.long2 <- vare.dist.long %>% mutate(Var2 = factor(Var2, levels = Var2[vare.hc$order]))
```

And then replacing `vare.dist.long` with `vare.dist.long3` in the plotting function.

Strangely, while ordering `Var1` (as in the `#Step 1` line) seems to work without complaint, when I try to do exactly the same thing to `Var2` (as in the `#Step 2` line) I get the following error:

> ```
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: factor level [2] is duplicated.
> Traceback:
>
> 1. vare.dist.long %>% mutate(Var2 = factor(Var2, levels = Var2[vare.hc$order]))
> 2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
> 3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
> 6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
> 7. withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
> 8. function_list[[k]](value)
> 9. mutate(., Var2 = factor(Var2, levels = Var2[vare.hc$order]))
> 10. mutate.data.frame(., Var2 = factor(Var2, levels = Var2[vare.hc$order]))
> 11. as.data.frame(mutate(tbl_df(.data), ...))
> 12. mutate(tbl_df(.data), ...)
> 13. mutate.tbl_df(tbl_df(.data), ...)
> 14. mutate_impl(.data, dots)
> ```

What am I missing here? Why can't I mutate `Var2`, which as far as I can tell is pretty much the same as `Var1` but in a different order?

Comment: Does `Var2[vare.hc$order]` have any repeated values? That would cause the error you're getting. If so, `unique(Var2[vare.hc$order])` should resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector provided to the `levels` argument should not have any duplicates. If you type the following to your console, you will see that you provided the same level to all the numbers in `Var2`.

```
vare.dist.long$Var2[vare.hc$order]
# [1] "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18"
# [19] "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18"
```

I think the following will work. `unique(Var1)` and `unique(Var2)` are to make sure there are no duplicates.

```
vare.dist.long1 <- vare.dist.long %>% mutate(Var1 = factor(Var1, levels = unique(Var1)[vare.hc$order]))

vare.dist.long2 <- vare.dist.long %>% mutate(Var2 = factor(Var2, levels = unique(Var2)[vare.hc$order]))
```

Comment: This absolutely works. I realize now that `unique(Var1)` and `unique(Var2)` and `vare.hc$labels` are all the same thing. I think the last of the three may be most intuitive (to me) since we are essentially saying that `vare.hc` tells you the order `vare.hc$order` the labels therein `vare.hc$lables` should be arranged.